# Determine if a time value exists in date/time string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime, time

I'm looking to write a method that will take a string and give me

1. The datetime value if a time value is provided in the string
2. The datetime value at the end of the day if only a date is provided in the string

I can use `[to_datetime][1]` to convert the string but I don't see a way to know if a time value was provided because the returned DateTime will initialize to `00:00:00 +0000` if a value isn't provided.

Right now this is a problem because `to_datetime` gives me a default value when I parse the input.

```
"1-1-2012".to_datetime            # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0000
"01/01/2012 23:59:59".to_datetime # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 23:59:59 +0000
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to convert the input so I know if a time value was provided?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh figured it out. I can use _parse to get the pieces:

```
DateTime._parse(date_only)
{:year=>2012, :mon=>1, :mday=>1}

DateTime._parse(date_and_time)
{:hour=>23, :min=>59, :sec=>59, :year=>2012, :mon=>1, :mday=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

First determine with a regex in what situation you are and then I would just add 1 day minus one second.

```
my_date_time = "1-1-2012".to_datetime + 1.days - 1.seconds
```

Comment: Right but I don't know if a Date was provided or a DateTime was provided. I only want to go to the end of the day if no time value is present in the string

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
date = '10/10/2000'
result = begin
           DateTime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
         rescue ArgumentError => e
           DateTime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').at_end_of_day
         end
```